# UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported [[node Cast (defined at C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/LSTM.py:132) ]]

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Creating error, but I can find what string they are referring to.
line 132: callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],

```
filepath = "LSTM_Final-{epoch:02d}" # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones

# Train model
history = model.fit(
    np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(np.array(validation_x), np.array(validation_y)),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)
```

Comment: tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\\{}".format(NAME))

Comment: post full error message.

Comment: `NAME = f"mylog"`

Comment: that's clearly not helpful. But try using `val_acc` instead of `val_loss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the data is labeled and the code will only accept unlabeled data. Unfortunately this was not indicated well by the error log.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code for `ModelCheckpoint()` but I'm going to assume that it takes a few parameters.

Edit: OP commented that it's from `keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()`. [The documentaiton](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) says this should fix it.

Note from documentation: `filepath` can contain named formatting options, which will be filled with the values of `epoch` and keys in `logs` (passed in `on_epoch_end`).

```py
filepath = "LSTM_Final-{epoch:02d}-{value_acc:.2f}"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

Comment: from my research the filepath string is used in format() and doesn't need an f for f-string

Comment: @mystack you're not calling format on `"LSTM_Final-{epoch:02d}"`.

Comment: @mystack what is this line doing? `checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\\{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max'))`? What do you want the first parameter to look like?

Comment: It creates a file in folder models called LSTM_Final-(the # of the epic that it is).model          Is that what you were asking of?

Comment: @mystack okay, I think I understand the issue. Updated.

Comment: Unfortunately the update didn't solve the problem. ModelCheckpoint is keras to save a model after an epoch.             `keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()`

Comment: @mystack why don't you post the full error message stack trace?

Comment: @mystack updated now. I read the keras documentation. I'd suggest reading this next time: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think that your code is perfect with this edit and now mine is as well. Unfortunately I'm still receiving the error.`filepath = "LSTM_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}"` I think I'll chalk it up to nargles and wait a few days for it to solve itself.